# ASP.NET CORE using ADO.NET with AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-core, ado.net, automapper

What is the proper way of using AutoMapper with ADO.NET in ASP.NET Core in generic way?
Also the SQL query has the same column names as in class of `<T>`
In specified example variable `result` is always empty list, so automapper could not map object properties to DbDataReader columns.

```
public class CustomDbContext : BaseRepository
{
    readonly DbConnection dbConn;
    public CustomDbContext(RepoDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        dbConn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(string sql) where T : class
    {
        var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DbDataReader, List<T>>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        await dbConn.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = dbConn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = sql;
            var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            var result = new List<T>();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                await reader.ReadAsync();
                result = mapper.Map<DbDataReader, List<T>>(reader);
            }
            reader.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Should I specify more detailed AutoMapper configuration or it can't be done this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using interfaces as `IDataReader` and `IEnumerable` instead of classes `DbDataReader` and List.

```
public async Task<List<T>> Get<T>(string sql) where T : class
{
    var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>();
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    await dbConn.OpenAsync();
    using (var command = dbConn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        var result = new List<T>();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            await reader.ReadAsync();
            result = mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>(reader).ToList();
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case `mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>(reader)` returns ` null`